# Open camera in middle of screen android for qr code

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to make a QR code scanner that is open in a fragment, I am using zxing library to do so. Now I can successfully open the camera to scan a QR code. However since I am using intent to open the camera it opens up another activity instead. What I am trying to do is open the camera within the fragment and only in the middle part of the screen. I am believing surface view and camera preview can help me do so but I am not sure how to implement it

```
public class QRscanner extends Fragment {
private IntentIntegrator qrScan;
public QRscanner() {
}
public static QRscanner newInstance(String text){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    QRscanner qrScanner = new QRscanner();
    qrScanner.setArguments(args);
    return qrScanner;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qr_scanner, container, false);
    IntentIntegrator qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
    qrScan.initiateScan();
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        //if qrcode has nothing in it
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //if qr contains data
            try {
                //converting the data to json
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                String testing = obj.getString("test");
                System.out.println(testing);
                //setting values to textviews
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //if control comes here
                //that means the encoded format not matches
                //in this case you can display whatever data is available on the qrcode
                //to a toast
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
}
```

[image: the dark block is the camera and the white is the rest of the screen]

Comment: You can use the following library : https://github.com/nipun-birla/QRReaderView

Answer (score 0):

Please visit  [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)  library on GitHub.

It might help you.